# StringVar instance has no attribute 'delete'

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am having trouble using the delete method for Entry in tkinter. Currently I import tkinter as follows:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

I then declare two variables that are used to track the value of two entry fields as follows:

```
self.UN = tk.StringVar()
self.PW = tk.StringVar()
```

I am able to get the value using

```
self.UN.get()
```

without any issue but when try to delete the value using

```
self.UN.delete(0, END)
```

I get the error, StringVar instance has no attribute 'delete'
I have looked through other possible solutions on SO but none seem relevant to my issue. I used the following tutorial to try and get this to work: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

I have also tried variations on the delete like putting Tk.END inside the brackets, but can't get this going. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's correct; `StringVar` objects don't have the `delete` method, `Entry` objects do.

Comment: In that case I am asking to call the delete in the wrong place, I completely misunderstood that, thanks for your help.

Comment: Just use `self.UN.set('')` if you want to clear the StringVar or use `self.UN.set('text')` to set it to a certain text, no deletion needed. For more info read about [Tkinter variable classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) on effbot.org

Comment: This has solved the problem completely. Can you post this as a proper answer so I can set it as accepted. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `delete()`, you have to use `set()`:

```
field_name.set('')
```

It's working from my side.

Comment: Check this link for knowing how to write a good answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/677018